# Python read file line by line and print for debug

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file line by line. This file has alot of lines.
Each line is formatted like for example:

```
data:otherdata1
data:someotherdata2
```

But for debug purposes I'm using a file with a few lines, same format.
And I'm trying to print those data.

But I'm getting the error:

```
print data.split(':')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is wrong? I'm really lost in this.

```
def process(data):
    print data.split(':') #printing for debug purposes
    return data

file = open("list.txt")
for line in file:
    process(line)
```

and yes I added `import fileinput`

Comment: You have the answer as to why this doesn't work - but what's `fileinput` got to do with anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Python3 with Python2 syntax.

In Python3, [`print` is a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), not a statement. So use

```
print(data.split(':'))
```

instead.